# Rendering VueJS components into a Google Map Infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to render a vue js component which is simply -

```
var infowindow_content = "<google-map-infowindow ";
infowindow_content += "content='Hello World'";
infowindow_content += "></google-map-infowindow>";
```

by passing it into the marker's infowindow

```
this.current_infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: infowindow_content,
});
this.current_infowindow.open(context.mapObject, marker);
```

And the vueJS component being -

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{content}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
    name: 'google-map-infowindow',
    props: [ 
        'content',
    ],
}
</script>
```

However, this doesn't work and the window is blank.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After revisiting this today I was able to do this by programmatically creating an instance of the vue component and mounting it before simply passing its rendered HTML template as the infowindow's content.

**InfoWindow.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{content}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
    name: 'infowindow',
    props: [ 
        'content',
    ],
}
</script>
```

And in the portion of the code that is required to create before opening the info-window:

```
...
import InfoWindowComponent from './InfoWindow.vue';
...

var InfoWindow = Vue.extend(InfoWindowComponent);
var instance = new InfoWindow({
    propsData: {
        content: "This displays as info-window content!"
    }
});

instance.$mount();

var new_infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: instance.$el,
});

new_infowindow.open(<map object>, <marker>);
```

Note: I haven't experimented with watchers and event-driven calls for this.

Comment: Can you explain why you needed to extend `InfoWindowComponent` to create `InfoWindow` instead of just creating an instance of `InfoWindowComponent` directly?

Answer (score 2):

**Vue3:**

Found the following solution for Vue3

```
import MapInfoWindow from "MapInfoWindow.vue";

var app = createApp(MapInfoWindow, { prop: "test" });

const content = document.createElement("div");
app.mount(content);
//document.body.appendChild(content); // Don't insert into actual DOM, but indirectly via infowindow

const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: content ,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In vue.js template interpolation with the "double moustaches" interprets its contents as plain text, not HTML (thus escaping it). If you want to emit HTML, you need to user the `v-html` directive:

```
<div v-html="content"></div>
```

For reference, see [Raw HTML](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) in the guide and the [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) API docs.

Note that in this way, data bindings are not considered, so I'm not really sure that manipulating raw HTML is the best strategy here.

Comment: `content` in the example though is just a string (or plain text).

Comment: I thought you passed the `<google-map-infowindow>...</google-map-infowindow>` HTML to the vue component through the `content` property. If not, what's the relation between the vue component and the `<google-map-infowindow>` / `this.current_infowindow` ?

Comment: So, `<google-map-infowindow>` is the component's tagname. I'm sending this as the html content for the infowindow, not to the component itself because that would make no sense. `this.current_infowindow` is nothing but an object-wide variable storing the reference to the infowindow object.

Comment: this doesn't make much sense to me, you are creating a vue `<google-map-infowindow>` component, but then you are creating it outside vue by passing the raw html to `google.maps.InfoWindow`... Maybe you'd be better served by a renderless Vue component (a component that doesn't have a template and doesn't render HTML on its own)? In this case the rendering would be done exclusively by the google library.