# How do I bind data to an element created with this.$createElement

Tags: google-maps, vue.js

I created an `InfoWindow` from Google maps and I want to put a vue component (specifically an input) inside the `content` property and bind it to a data. I'm also using vuetify and if possible, I want to use it's `VTextfield` component. If not, then a regular input would be ok as well.

Example:

**data**

```js
data () {
  return {
    inputVal: null
  }
}
```

**methods**

```js
renderInfoWindow () {
  let input = /* create an input and bind it to inputVal  */
  return new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: input
  })
}
```

Comment: Try `content: this.inputVal`

Comment: But I won't be able to make an input field that way.

Comment: There's probably a better way of doing this but your **inputVal** can become inputVal: `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` **JSX style** and then pass it to **content** ```content: this.inputVal``` - I am not sure whether you can pass a whole component to **content**

Comment: How am I going to use that inside a the `renderInfoWindow` function? And the input is a text box not a submit. I want to bind the `inputVal` in the **input from the content property** of infowindow

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Template Compilation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Template-Compilation) section in the docs,

```
<input v-model="inputVal">
```

is this render function:

```
function anonymous(
) {
    with(this){
        return _c('input', {
            directives: [{
                name: "model",
                rawName: "v-model",
                value: (inputVal),
                expression: "inputVal"
            }],
            domProps: { "value": (inputVal) },
            on: {
                "input": function($event) {
                    if ($event.target.composing)
                        return;
                    inputVal=$event.target.value
                }
            },
        })
    }
}
```

I haven't used render functions yet, so I hope this is what you need.

Comment: `<input v-model="inputVal">` is that a template string inside the `content` property of infoWindow? And I don't get where the `_c` from the `return _c` came from. And which part of my code will I put the `function anonymous`?

Comment: @Marcus I think I misunderstood your question then. Is this what you're trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50088994/rendering-vuejs-components-into-a-google-map-infowindow ?