# How to get the compiled html content of a component in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component like this `<AgentCard :agent="agent" />`, where `agent` is an object with properties like `FirstName, LastName, Recent Orders` etc...

Now I need to show this component inside a Google Maps InfoBox. The `infoWindow.setContent()` method (*the Google Maps API to display the popup info window*) accepts only an HTML string, so I am trying to render the `<AgentCard>` manually, get the HTML content of the rendered component, and pass it on to the `setContent()` method.

I tried `Vue.compile('<AgentCard :agent="agent" />').render()`, but this doesnt work. How do I render a Vue component manually, and get its HTML content?

Comment: Give your component a ref then access that ref's inner HTML. `this.$refs.foo.$el.innerHTML`

Comment: I don't want to render this component elsewhere in the dom. That  is the concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to create a new Vue instance with only the target component, [`$mount`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount) it, and then get the [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) of its [`$el` (root element)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el):

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<script>
Vue.component('AgentCard', {
  template: `<div>{{agent.name}}</div>`,
  props: {
    agent: Object
  }
})

const app = new Vue({
  template: `<AgentCard :agent="agent" />`,
  data: () => ({ agent: { name: 'john doe' } })
}).$mount()

console.log(app.$el.outerHTML)
</script>
```

Comment: How we can do the same thing with vue 3?

Comment: What about the following solution using Vue3 technique: [Rendering VueJS components into a Google Map Infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74171084/10026085)

Comment: How to use a render function instead of a template string? (Which won't work if you are using the non-cdn version which is compiler-less).

Comment: on Vue 3 I was able to do like this:

`
        const componentDiv = document.createElement("div");
        createApp(MyComponent, { myProp: "here" }).mount(componentDiv);
        console.log(componentDiv.innerHTML);
`

Answer (score 2):

on Vue 3:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";    
const componentDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
createApp(MyComponent, { myProp: "here" }).mount(componentDiv); 
console.log(componentDiv.innerHTML);
```