# Snapshot of HTML in Vue3 Proxy object or vitual DOM

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, virtual-dom

Printing javascript "Proxy" object wrapping my virtual Vue3 app perfectly displays a specific value I would like to extract.

`console.log(proxyVueApp)` ...outputs beautiful HTML deep down in `proxyVueApp.$.vnode.el.outerHTML`.

Accessing the prop directly with `console.log(proxyVueApp.$.vnode.el)` gives me a HTML-comment because it's a virtual DOM: `<!---->`. `console.log(proxyVueApp.$.vnode.el.outerHTML)` is `undefined`.

**Is there a way to grap this HTML one way or the other?**

Now for the details.
Here is how I create my Vue instance, import a dynamic component and mount it all:

```
const proxyVueApp = createApp({
    render() {
        const relPath = 'some/path';
        const compReference = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
            import(relPath /* @vite-ignore */)
        );
        return h(compReference);
    },
});
const el = document.createElement('div');
const mountedApp = proxyVueApp.mount(el);
```

Is there no way to extract the HTML im seeing with my own eyes from either my `mountedApp` or HTMLObjectThingo `el`? I feel like I'm dealing with a case of Schrödingers cat here. The element is both dead and alive.

Comment: It would be easier if you use same names in the text and in the code example. Did you try to extract the HTML from mounted app ? [Working example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68319134/381282)

Comment: @MichalLevý yeah nah HTML is undefined in mounted app (as stated in the question). No difference if I try to access $el or $. There must be some life cycle differences between my context and the working example linked. But no worries I got it working (see below).

Comment: It is not about lifecycle. The main difference is you are using async component and normal (no SSR) Vue app `mount()` is sync (not returning a promise). This is something SSR renderer must handle

Comment: @MichalLevý right, ofcourse. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the way [SSR](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#basic-tutorial) works to achieve your goal

```
import { createSSRApp } from 'vue'
import { renderToString } from 'vue/server-renderer'

const app = createSSRApp({
  data: () => ({ count: 1 }),
  template: `<button @click="count++">{{ count }}</button>`
})

renderToString(app).then((html) => {
  // this is what you want
  console.log(html)
})
```

Comment: "@vue/server-renderer" library was just what I needed. Thanks.
The SSR way is not possible for me, as I am doing it in a ESM module in a Storybook lifecycle. No worries it works fine with `createApp({ render() { return h(MyVueComponent) }});`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my complete solution based on Duannx answer. It's taken out a Storybook lifecycle context:

```
import { createApp, defineAsyncComponent, h } from 'vue';
import { renderToString } from '@vue/server-renderer';

let html = '';
const tempApp = createApp({
        render() {
            const relPath = 'path/to/component.vue';
            const compReference = defineAsyncComponent(() => import(relPath));
            return h(compReference);
        }
    });
renderToString(tempApp).then((h) => {
        html = h;
});
```