# Vuetify components inside infoWindow from google maps

Tags: google-maps, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vue-composition-api

I'm using google maps inside my vue 3 composition API app, displaying the infoWindows in Markers (without any vue google maps library, directly from google maps api), I'd like to use vuetify components inside the infoWindow box not just raw html, any idea how can I achieve this? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50088994/rendering-vuejs-components-into-a-google-map-infowindow) related question is outdated...

I think mounting a vue component and passing it as a vue app (using vue directive createApp) would do the trick but it shows as plain text when firing the click event on infowindow, here is my code where I need to put the infoWindows:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { onMounted, ref, createApp } from "vue";
    import infowindowVue from "./infowindow.vue";

    const position = { lat: 63.42805, lng: 10.41033 };
    let googleMap = ref<google.maps.Map>();

    onMounted(async () => {
        const { Map } = (await google.maps.importLibrary(
            "maps"
        )) as google.maps.MapsLibrary;

        googleMap.value = new Map(
            document.getElementById("googleMap") as HTMLElement,
            {
                center: position,
                zoom: 4,
            }
        );
        let InfoWindow = createApp(infowindowVue, {
            content: "<v-btn>hola</v-btn>",
        });

        const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
        InfoWindow.mount(wrapper);

        const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: wrapper,
            ariaLabel: "Trondheim",
        });

        let map = googleMap.value;

        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position,
            map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: "punto de interés",
        });

        marker.addListener("click", () => {
            infowindow.open({
                anchor: marker,
                map,
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <v-row justify="center">
            <v-col cols="12" class="pa-0">
                <div id="googleMap" ref="googleMap"></div>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>
<style scope>
    #googleMap {
        height: 500px;
        width: inherit;
    }
</style>
```

and here you can see the simple component **infoWindow**:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    defineProps<{
        content: string;
    }>();

</script>
<template>
    <div>
        {{ content }}
    </div>
</template>
```